# Saving Omniauth data between actions

Tags: facebook, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

in omniauth-facebook, facebook sometimes do not supply an email for the user (for those who registered with a phone number).

so the routine is normal if an email was supplied, but if it wasn't I need to redirect the user to a form so they could input their email manually.

The problem is that I need to keep the data received from facebook for later to create the user once the email is supplied.

Saving it in session['devise.facebook.data'] results in cookie overflow (in Rails 4,  due the encryption). Using cookies would turn the whole thing into a long string, which will make it harder to pull data from there

Is there a better way to pass the data to the next action?

Comment: Why are you putting every bit of information you receive from OmniAuth into the session? Try to just store the information you need. Most of the time you don't need the "extra" information, so this would certainly work: `session[devise.facebook.data'] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra'). If you really need some information contained in the "extra" field, then create your own, smaller hash and store it in the session.

Comment: thanks, thats what I ended up doing

Comment: I'm glad it was a problem simple to solve! It would have been harder if you really needed all that information.